# Bloquear el reCAPTCHA de Google

Tags: recaptcha

¿Sería posible bloquear el reCAPTCHA de Google hasta que el usuario acepte las cookies para cumplir con el RGPD?
Utilizo reCAPTCHA v3 en una web con WordPress y WooCommerce. Utilizo Contact Form 7 para los formularios. Quiero que el reCAPTCHA me sirva para bloquear el SPAM en los formularios, pero también para proteger el registro de nuevos clientes y el formulario de compras. El problema es que reCAPTCHA utiliza cookies del tipo analítico y, de acuerdo con el RGPD, el usuario debe aceptar estas cookies antes de que se instalen. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Gracias de antemano.

Un saludo

Comment: Es correcto, no puedes usar reCaptcha si el usuario no ha aceptado las cookies. Una posible solución es evitar el envío del formulario si no se aceptan las cookies. Lamentablemente, el servicio reCaptcha de Google, captura datos específicamente para su análisis y evitar el spam. Saludos

Comment: Otra alternativa es usar un *honeypot* o tu propio captcha, o ambos a la vez. De esa forma dejas tu formulario totalmente operativo con o sin cookies. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio. Lo del honeypot es interesante. Lo que me preocupa es que no sea tan seguro como reCAPTCHA. Por otra parte no sólo quiero proteger los formularios de Contact Form 7, sino que quiero minimizar el riesgo de que los bots se registren en la página de "Mi cuenta" en WooCommerce, y también en el formulario de "Finalizar compra" donde los clientes introducen sus datos. He visto que hay varios plugins de tipo honeypot para WordPress pero, teniendo todo esto en cuenta ¿Cuál me conviene instalar? Muchas gracias de antemano. Un saludo

Comment: Para registro de clientes deberías usar verificación por correo. De esa forma evitas registros fantasmas. En cuanto a lo de plugins, no puedo decirte nada porque desconozco sobre los mismos, ya que particularmente no trabajo con *Wordpress* y sus derivados. Lo siento. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio. ¿Cómo puedo implementar esa verificación por correo? Gracias de antemano. Un saludo